# problem using pip to install local package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, confluent-platform

i'm a bit new to python but i need to install a library on a linux machine, im using python 2.7.

The challenge is that I'm behind a firewall and don't have a proxy to do an actual `pip install confluent-kafka-python`

So i got the confluent-kafka-python.zip from github so i could install offline and did the following:

```
sudo pip install confluent-kafka-python-master.zip
```

but i get the following error:

```
    Collecting futures (from confluent-kafka==0.11.6)
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1846e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/futures/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1846390>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/futures/
      ....
```

what can i do to install this library offline?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your package's dependancies, download them locally (like you did for confluent-kafka), and [install them with the '--no-index' option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages).

You may also want to [check this page for more on installing local packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages).